# Horizontal GSAP pinning with ScrollTrigger

Tags: html, jquery, css, gsap, scrolltrigger

I just created pen in `CodePen` for my demo. I try with different states but did not work.
I want to add and remove class in middle section like this: https://codepen.io/Designer12/pen/qBryyrp

Demo image:

[image: Demo image]

Comment: Please don't use caps, It's consider shouting and it's rude

Comment: Thanks for suggestion 
I am new so thanks again

Comment: Also `I want to add and remove class in middle section like this` is a very unclear description of the problem. What class do you want to add/remove? Please specify the problem

Comment: means I want to add active class for create yellow effect in middle section like demo image

Comment: In the middle... the first and last item of your list never reach the middle of the page. Please explain better.

Comment: Ohh yes you are right basically I try like this [brights.io] In that site section named "Our software development services" I want to try like this but as demo image centermode

Comment: Carsten Løvbo Andersen and prettyInPink 
any solution for that

Comment: Of course there is a solution, there always is. You can't assume someone will simply code this out for you. Please try to achieve this on your own. Whenever you are stuck on what you've tried, reach out.

Comment: you use ScrollTrigger, not ScrollMagic! its different plugins.

Comment: The question requires you to include code in the question itself when linking to somewhere like CodePen. This is for good reason. Please don't syntax highlight a random word in order to get around this restriction but instead include the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the `onUpdate` event, divided the progress (from zero to 1) by the number of elements (panels) and get the active frame:

**Better check** [**Codepen answer**](https://codepen.io/gregOnCodePen/pen/BaWPvLz), **snippet have some lags**

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
console.clear()
let container = document.querySelector(".portfolio");
let tl = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    pin: true,
    scrub: 1,
    trigger: container,
    end: () => container.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  onUpdate: ({progress, direction, isActive}) => changeActive(progress)
  },
  defaults: { ease: "none", duration: 1 }
});
tl.to(".parallax", { x: 300 })
  .to(".panel", { x: () => -(container.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth) }, 0)
  .from(".secondAn", {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.5,
    duration: 0.2,
    stagger: {
      amount: 0.8
    }
  }, 0);

gsap.from(".firstAn", {
  duration: 1,
  opacity: 0,
  scale: .5,
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: container,
    start: "top 90%",
    end: "bottom 10%",
    toggleActions: "play none none reverse"
  }
});

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')
let active = NaN;
function changeActive(progress){
  let oneElement = 1 / (elements.length - 1)
  let activeItem = Math.round(progress.toFixed(3) /oneElement)
  if(active != activeItem){
      active = activeItem
      changeBackground(active)
  }
  console.log("active ", activeItem)
}

function changeBackground(active){
  elements.forEach((e)=>{
      e.classList.remove("bg")
  })
  console.log(active, elements.length)
  elements[active].classList.add("bg")
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}
body { 
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.spacer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #000;
}
.section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: #1F242D;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio_title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -15rem;
    font-size: 24rem;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #343A42;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-stroke {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #343A42;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  aling-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
  padding: 10rem 7rem 2rem 7rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel_item {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.panel_img {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js?r=5426'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ScrollTrigger.min.js'></script>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <div class="spacer">
        <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    </div>

    <section class="section portfolio">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel_item">
                <div class="panel_item_content">
                    <div class="panel_item_circle"></div>
                    <h1>Dedicated Web Development</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna ali</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="spacer">
        <h1>The End</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```